# update_post_meta not working in wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I have a bit of code in my functions file that is looping over posts and then adding together facebook and google plus likes for the post and storing the value in the post meta, however it has only saved the value in the post_meta once - it is not updating!

What is my problem here, why is it not updating?

Here is my code:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

// Get Facebook Likes From FB Graph API
$data = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id='. get_permalink());
$obj = json_decode($data);
$like_no = intval($obj->{'shares'});

$html =  file_get_contents( "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=".urlencode(get_permalink()));
    $doc = new DOMDocument();   $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $counter=$doc->getElementById('aggregateCount');
    $google_no = $counter->nodeValue;

   $shares_total = $like_no + $google_no;

// Add Facebook Likes to Post Meta
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_mn_fb_likes', $shares_total);

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Are those values changing? by default wordpress' `update_post_meta()` is going to return `false` if the data being inserted is the same as the data that exists

Comment: yes @Ohgodwhy I've just changed the $args array just to test and nothing is happening

Comment: can you dump the value of the return from `update_post_meta()` for us?

Comment: if I do that im guessing it will be a pretty huge array, as its looping through all of my posts

Comment: Can you put it in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for us Further, we just need to see 1 iteration, so just use a marker so it doesn't dump every post.

Comment: when I print_r'd it i was just getting 11111111...

Comment: can you see any issues with my code above @Ohgodwhy?

Answer (score 1):

[`$query->the_post();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods) should set up the global `$post` variable for you, so you should be able to replace

```
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_mn_fb_likes', $shares_total);
```

with

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_mn_fb_likes', $shares_total );
```

If the problem is your `get_the_ID()` call, this should fix it. (I'm not 100% sure that's the issue, but at least this will eliminate it as a potential culprit.)